# ARCore AnchorNode.setOnTapListener

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to add `onTapListener` to a node, but a code inside of it is never being called. Can someone spot a mistake I am doing?

```
private fun addNodeToScene(fragment: ArFragment, createAnchor: Anchor, renderable: ModelRenderable) {
    val anchorNode = AnchorNode(createAnchor)
    anchorNode.setOnTapListener{_,_ ->
        buttonasd.text = "asdasd" // this line is never called
    }

    val transformableNode = TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem)
    transformableNode.renderable = renderable
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
    fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
    transformableNode.select()
}
```

Comment: You had any luck with this? The solution provided below isn't working for me. Thank you

Comment: transferablenode.setOnTapListener() it serve the purpose for use. ypu dont have to do anything other than this

Answer (score 1):

to make it works you shold do following :

```
    private fun addNodeToScene(fragment: ArFragment, createAnchor: Anchor, renderable: ModelRenderable) {
    val anchorNode = AnchorNode(createAnchor)

    val transformableNode = TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem).apply {
        setOnTapListener { _, _ ->
            //TODO your action
            }

        }
        transformableNode.localPosition = Vector3(0f,0.3f,0f)
        transformableNode.renderable = renderable
        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
        fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
        transformableNode.select()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a slightly different approach, like this:

```
private var grid = Array(ROW_NUM) { 
    arrayOfNulls<TranslatableNode>(COL_NUM) 
}

val anchorNode = AnchorNode(hitResult.createAnchor())
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.arSceneView.scene)

grid.matrixIndices { col, row ->
    val renderableModel = droidRenderable?.makeCopy() ?: return@matrixIndices
    TranslatableNode().apply {
        setParent(anchorNode)
        renderable = renderableModel
        addOffset(x = row * spacing, z = col * spacing)
        grid[col][row] = this
        this.setOnTapListener { _, _ ->
            // button.text = "asdasd"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.